# Is it safe to reuse multiple models with the same generic view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a project with around 60 models so creating a unique Detail, Create, Update, Delete APIView for each would be a lot of wasted resources (or so it feels like). Would it be better performance-wise (or safe?) to simply create a generic view that could cycle between each model like so?

```
_CLASSES = <Dictionary of my classes>
class GenericModelView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, model_name):  # model_name would be a required part of the URL.
        model_class = _CLASSES[model_name]
        serializer_class = model_class.serializer_class  # I would instantiate a serializer for each model_class
        return Response(serializer_class(model_class.objects.all()).data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there should not be any concerns safety wise. However, in my experience, this approach will not last long. You will have to customize the functionality for different model according to the requirements. At that stage, you will need to create separate views. Also, it may become complicated to read and understand logs as always same function is being called. So my final recommendation would be to use different views. It should not take you more than an hour. Just copy and paste. Customize later according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Arvind! If it's safe then it's a risk I'm willing to take as I already have a similar project running with unique View classes and it just feels so bloated